# NSTimer memory leak?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

Will the following cause a memory leak or could it be changed to be better somehow? With the `countDownTimer = nil` being removed

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{    
  countDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadNewTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)pauseTimer{            
   NSLog(@"Fired");
   [countDownTimer invalidate];
   //countDownTimer = nil <------ Causes crash when run
}

-(void)resumeTimer{
   countDownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadNewTime:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSTimer automatically decrements its retain count when it expires or is invalidated.  There is no need to set it equal to nil unless you have assigned it to an ivar that retains. (which in your case means you would have also needed to assign the timer using self.countDownTimer

Answer (score 6):

One can use `block` variant of `scheduleTimer`method to avoid retain cycles.

```swift
var timer = Timer()

func startTimer() {
  timer = Timer.scheduleTimer(withTimerInterval: 1.0, repeats: true, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
     self?.performUpdate(timer: timer)
  })
}

func stopTimer() {
   timer.invalidate()
}
```

Just make sure to capture `self` as a `weak` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `countDownTimer` is an ivar? `NSTimer`s retain their targets while they're alive, so it sounds like your call to `[countDownTimer invalidate]` is releasing the last reference to `self` and causing `self` to deallocate in the middle of your `-pauseTimer` method. As such, any reference to `self`, even implicit references (e.g. accessing ivars) is going to crash, or at least behave unexpectedly.

Who is calling `-pauseTimer`? Perhaps they should have a strong reference to your object.